# primefaces <p:datatable> <p:commandlink> fires another <h:link> accidentally

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i got two cases of strange behaviour in my `p:dataTable` . First when i try to call the `h:link` with the `f:param` the link always sends the same id. Always the id from the first entry. 
The bigger problem is when i push on the commandbutton the `h:link` gets called though this behavior was completely not expected. Especially without the right Parameters.
Is this a Bug or am i doing something wrong?
When i delete the `h:link` everything works like expected. 
I would appreciate any help in this matter

My Primefaces Version is 3.5 and im working with Liferay 6.1 on Tomcat 7. With the newest FacesBridge

```
<h:form id="serviceForm">
     <p:dataTable id="newServicesTable" var="service" value="#{cloudServicesBean.newServices}" rowKey="service.serviceId" selection="#{cloudServicesBean.selectedService}">
                <p:column headerText="Servicename">
                 <h:link  outcome="/views/cloudservice/overview.xhtml" includeViewParams="true" value="#{service.serviceName}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{service.serviceId}"/>
                         <f:param name="selectedServiceId" value="#{service.serviceId}" />
                    </h:link>   
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Provider">
                    <h:outputText value="#{adminBean.getOrganizationNameForId(service.providerId)}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Datum">
                    <h:outputText value="#{service.createDate}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Aktionen" rendered="#{adminBean.isUserAdministrator()}">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check"  action="#{cloudServicesBean.setServiceApproved}" update=":serviceForm">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{service}" target="#{cloudServicesBean.selectedService}" />
                    </p:commandButton>

            </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: You can try `rowIndexVar="index"` instead `rowKey` then pass the value via f:param value="#{index}"`. This should fix the set first element problem.

Comment: Unless you mistyped that, you must include an EL expression in your `rowKey` attribute. That means `#{service.serviceId}` instead of `service.serviceId`. The second issue I can see is that you're giving `h:link` a value and also putting `h:outputText` inside, which is basically redundant.

Comment: when i use index, the value is always 0, also the redundancy didnt help. I always get the same selectedServiceId. Suprisingly the outputText with the serviceId is correct. but not the Param which is always the same id. Even if i put a hard coded param parameter in another column with i fix id it has the same id like every other param valued :(

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I run Primefaces 3.5 with Liferay 6.0.11 on Tomcat 7. When I switched the Liferay JSF dependencies from version 3.1.2.ga3 to 3.1.3-ga4 the issue was resolved.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>liferay-faces-alloy</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>liferay-faces-bridge-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>liferay-faces-portal</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
```